# Migrations with 1 database and N schemas (1 schema per tenant) with Entity Framework core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, multi-tenant

After implementing all the multi tenancy code in my webapi using 1 database with 1 schema (Using mysql, I can't use multi schemas in a database) I have decided to move to a multi schema scenario (1 database and multiple schemas). For this, I have decided to move to postgre database that suports multi schema databases.

I have read a lot about how to implement the multitenancy with multiple schemas and I think I have this covered but the problem is how should I create migrations for this kind of database. It will have N identically schemas. One for each tenant and of course the number is not fixed. A new customer can register in the system and a new schema should be created for him/her.

If I for example decide to add a new column to the schema, how do you do to spread the change along all schemas in the database with entity framework core migrations or any other solution?

I know there are other questions on SO about this, but they are not answered or are too old and doesn't work nowadays.

Comment: As a side note to your actually question, you can implement a multitenant design using Pomelo by either using multiple databases (e.g. one for each tenant), or using a singe database and use multiple schemas in EF Core, but let them translate to tables like `schemaname_tablename` (users to those tables can be [granted](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) access only to their tenants tables). For translating a schema name and a table name to a table with Pomelo, see the [corresponding PR](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/pull/982).

Comment: You could also use [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters). But from experience, the simples solution (which is the best most of the time) is to use one database for each tenant. It's the most flexible with the fewest limitations (e.g. tenants can even be on different servers). If you want to share, what concrete problem you are trying to solve with the multitenant approach, we might be able to provide you with some further advice from experience or at least some best practices.